# how to access form data using flask?

Tags: python, flask, curl

My `login` endpoint looks like

```
@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.form # debug line, see data printed below
        user = User.get(request.form['uuid'])
        if user and hash_password(request.form['password']) == user._password:
            login_user(user, remember=True)  # change remember as preference
            return redirect('/home/')
    else:
        return 'GET on login not supported'
```

When I test this using `curl`, the `GET` call looks like

```
⮀ ~PYTHONPATH ⮀ ⭠ 43± ⮀ curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/login/
GET on login not supported
```

but on `POST`, I am not able to access the form data and get `HTTP 400`

```
⮀ ~PYTHONPATH ⮀ ⭠ 43± ⮀ curl -d "{'uuid': 'admin', 'password': 'admin'}" http://127.0.0.1:5000/login/
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
```

On the server though, my debug information prints the following

```
ImmutableMultiDict([("{'uuid': 'admin', 'password': 'admin'}", u'')])
```

where I do `print request.form`. I am not able to understand where I am doing wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not using `curl` correctly. Try like this:

```
curl -d 'uuid=admin&password=admin'
```

The `400 Bad Request` error is the usual behavior when you try to get nonexistent keys from `request.form`.

Alternatively, use `request.json` instead of `request.form` and call `curl` like this:

```
curl -d '{"uuid":"admin","password":"admin"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Answer (score 6):

You still need to return a response:

```
from flask import abort

@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User.get(request.form['uuid'])

        if user and hash_password(request.form['password']) == user._password:
            login_user(user, remember=True)
            return redirect('/home/')
        else:
            return abort(401)  # 401 Unauthorized
    else:
        return abort(405)  # 405 Method Not Allowed
```

Here's the documentation for [custom Flask error pages](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/errorpages/#error-handlers).

Also, take a look at [Flask-Bcrypt](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bcrypt/) for password hashing.

---

Your CURL command line isn't valid. JSON objects need to have double quotes around the keys and values:

```
$ curl -d '{"uuid": "admin", "password": "admin"}' http://127.0.0.1:5000/login/
```

Now, you can access the keys with `request.json`.

Comment: Thanks @Blender, but the question is why I am not able to access `uuid` when I am sending the data form client?

Comment: @daydreamer: Flask sends that response only if you access a key that doesn't exist in the [`request.form` object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#the-request-object). Try using `request.form.get('uuid', None)`.

Comment: As mentioned in my question, my `request.form` is `ImmutableMultiDict([("{'uuid': 'admin', 'password': 'admin'}", u'')])`

Comment: @daydreamer: I know. How are you sending this request?

Comment: like this `curl -X POST -d '{uuid: "admin", "password": "admin"}' http://127.0.0.1:5000/login/`

Comment: @daydreamer: You're sending a JSON object with the POST request, not a regular form POST request. Use `response.json` to access it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27705/discussion-between-daydreamer-and-blender)